# Replying potential PhD supervisor with documents

Tags: phd, professorship, email

I applied for PhD at a University and receive a mail from the supervisor, he asked me to mail my cv and transcript. I am thinking to reply like this:

> Dear Professor XXX,
>
> Thank you for your reply.
>
> I have attached my grade sheet and resume, with references, to this email.
>
> Thanks for your consideration.
>
> YYY

Is it sufficient and decent?

Comment: I am not a native English speaker and haven't mailed many  profs so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is sufficient and decent.

Only point I'd note is that if your transcript is not in English, be sure to include a translation. You might also need an explanation of what the grades actually mean (e.g. is your grade measured on a 4.0 scale, or on a 100-point scale?).

Comment: Glad my edit was ok then...

Comment: Thank @SolarMike and Allure